# NVIDIA Proprietary Driver: "Error while installing package"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I seem to have borked my NVIDIA drivers. Ubuntu 19.10 was working just fine out of the box until I tried to switch to another version of the NVIDIA drivers using the Software & Updates utility. The error message linked below seems to reference a package that doesn't exist: pk-client-error-quark. Uninstalling and reinstalling the metapackages doesn't seem to have helped. FWIW, I've got a pair of GTX970 set up to run SLI. If you've seen this error before, please let me know what might resolve it. Many thanks!

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUrz0.png)